# stored procedure error:Subquery returns more than 1 rows

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to create a stored procedure but giving me an error: Subquery returns more than 1 row  for the below query . This could be done using cursors but are there any other ways to directly run this query in  stored procedures without using cursors since there are multiple queries of this type which i need to add in stored procedure for multiple tables.

Query:-

```
UPDATE ipcc_patent_ipc_class
SET assignee_type = (
SELECT IF(ipcc_patent_master.assignee_type='$ipcc_config_param[0]',$ipcc_config_value[0],IF(ipcc_patent_master.assignee_type='$ipcc_config_param[1]',$ipcc_config_value[1],null))
FROM ipcc_patent_master
WHERE ipcc_patent_ipc_class.patent_id = patent_uid);
```

But this Query Works for multiple field:-

```
UPDATE ipcc_patent_ipc_class
SET geographies_id=(
  SELECT ipcc_geographies.geographies_uid
  FROM ipcc_patent_master,ipcc_geographies
  WHERE ipcc_patent_master.geographies = ipcc_geographies.geographies
  AND ipcc_patent_ipc_class.patent_id = ipcc_patent_master.patent_uid
),
jurisdictions_id =(
  SELECT ipcc_jurisdictions.jurisdisctions_uid
  FROM ipcc_patent_master,ipcc_jurisdictions
  WHERE ipcc_patent_master.jurisdictions = ipcc_jurisdictions.jurisdictions
  AND ipcc_patent_ipc_class.patent_id = ipcc_patent_master.patent_uid
),
country_code_id =(
  SELECT ipcc_country_code.country_code_uid
  FROM ipcc_patent_master,ipcc_country_code
  WHERE ipcc_patent_master.country_code= ipcc_country_code.country_code
  AND ipcc_patent_ipc_class.patent_id = ipcc_patent_master.patent_uid
);
```

Comment: Can you quote exact error and the exact SQL with which you are *trying* to create the SP?

Answer (score 2):

Add Limit clause in your sub query.

Comment: Limit did not solve the problem since the same query when running through php script or mysql query browser gives the desired output  by updating multiple rows but when added into stored procedure gives the above error.

Comment: Did you put the limit in the update or the select? I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Add more terms to your subquery's `WHERE` clause to bring it down to one record, or add a `LIMIT` clause to the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a subquery here at all. You can reference multiple tables directly in the UPDATE query:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: i have added a condition in select query..How could that be possible using update???

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
for the subquery (SELECT Statement), alias was missing for patent_uid which lead to this error.
After entering the table name as alias,it started working properly inside stored procedure..

Thanks Guys for your kind help...